# Proof-Verification: $\int_a^b \left|\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}\right|{\rm d}x>\frac{4}{b-a}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Suppose that $f(x)$ has twice order continuous derivative over $[a,b]$, $\forall x \in [a,b]:f''(x)<0$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0.$ Prove $$\displaystyle \int_a^b \left|\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}\right|{\rm d}x>\frac{4}{b-a}.$$

## Proof

Since $f''(x)<0$, then $f(x)$ is concave over $[a,b]$. Hence, $\forall x \in (a,b):f(x)>0$. Moreover, since $f(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$, it can reach its maximum value at some point $x=c \in (a,b)$,namely $\max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}f(x)=f(c)>0$ and $f'(c)=0$. Therefore
$$\int_a^b \left|\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}\right|{\rm d}x=-\int_a^b \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}{\rm d}x> -\int_a^b \frac{f''(x)}{f(c)}{\rm d}x=\frac{f'(a)-f'(b)}{f(c)}.\tag{0}$$
By Taylor's formula, we obtain
$$f(c)=f'(a)(c-a)+\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{2}(c-a)^2<f'(a)(c-a)\tag{1}$$
$$f(c)=f'(b)(c-b)+\frac{f''(\xi_2)}{2}(c-b)^2<f'(b)(c-b)\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$, we obtain
$$\frac{f'(a)}{f(c)}>\frac{1}{c-a}.\tag{3}$$
From $(2)$, we obtain
$$-\frac{f'(b)}{f(c)}>\frac{1}{b-c}.\tag{4}$$
By $(3)+(4)$
$$\frac{f'(a)-f'(b)}{f(c)}>\frac{1}{c-a}+\frac{1}{b-c}.\tag{5}$$
By HM-AM inequality
$$\frac{2}{\dfrac{1}{c-a}+\dfrac{1}{b-c}}\leq \frac{(c-a)+(b-c)}{2}=\frac{b-a}{2}.\tag{6}$$
which implies
$$\frac{1}{c-a}+\frac{1}{b-c}\geq \frac{4}{b-a}.\tag{7}$$
Combining $(0)$ and $(7)$, it follows that
$$\int_a^b \left|\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}\right|{\rm d}x>\frac{4}{b-a},$$
which is what we want to prove.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @zhw. it is $f^{(2)}(x)$！

Comment: Try again: Is $f''<0$ on all of $[a,b]?$

Comment: @zhw u r right！

Comment: There is a typo in (2): $(c-a)^2$ should be $(c-b)^2$. Apart from that your proof looks good to me.

Comment: @MartinR THX！ Corrected！

Comment: Related: [If nonnegative $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous $f''$, then $\int_0^1 \Big| \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} \Big| \,dx >4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038966/42969)

Answer (score 2):

The integral equals $\infty$ in all cases.

Proof: From concavity we see $f'(a)>0.$ Since concave functions stay below their tangent lines, we have $f(x) \le f'(a)(x-a)$ for $x\in [a,b].$ We are also given that $|f''| \ge m$ on $[a,b]$ for some $m>0.$ Thus

$$\int_a^b \left |\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}\right |\, dx \ge \int_a^b \frac{m}{f'(a)(x-a)}\, dx=\infty.$$

Comment: I just wonder if the condition should actually be $f''(x) < 0$ on the *open* interval $(a, b)$ for the question to make sense. In that case $\sin(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$ would be an example where the integral is finite.

Comment: You're probably right @MartinR  I did check with the OP on this however.